# C# Concept Unboxing

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

I'm trying to learn C# Boxing and Unboxing Concept.
I filled the list of objects with integers and then I wanted to summarize them as result in console output.

```
List<object> listOfObjects = new List<object>();
//var listOfObjects = new List<object>();

//adding first string to list
listOfObjects.Add("First string");

//adding integers to list
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    listOfObjects.Add(j);
}
listOfObjects.Add("Second string");
for (int k = 5; k < 10; k++)
{
    listOfObjects.Add(k);
}
foreach (var obj in listOfObjects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
var sum = 0;
for (var l = 0;  l < 4;  l++)
{
    sum += (int)listOfObjects[l];            
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

but output throws exception

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in ConsoleApp.exe
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred

```
sum += (int)listOfObjects[l] // this unboxing cause compile error
```

Someone knows why? 
I used the example from [MSDN resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Comment: This is because you are adding `string`s as well to your `listOfObjects` - `listOfObjects.Add("First string");`. You cannot directly convert any string to an `int` through a cast.

Comment: You are adding `First string` to your list, then you are trying to sum it with other int values !!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine( listOfObjects.OfType<int>().Sum());` with `using System.Linq;` will filter/cast all int values from your object list and sum them up. Unboxing with a can opener :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `listOfObjects` is a `List` whose contents are of type `object`, you can add anything to it. You first add a `string`, which is an object. Then you add a bunch of numbers of type `int`, which is a *value type*, so the numbers are *boxed* into an `object` before they are added to the list. Then you add another `string`. Then you add another bunch of numbers of type `int`, again boxing as before.

Your problem is in the last loop, where you loop over the first 4 elements. The first element is a `string`, so you cannot cast it to an int.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is lines like these:

`listOfObjects.Add("First string");`

This adds a `string` to the list and it makes no sense to try to convert that to an `int`.

Remove lines such as this and you should get an output.

Answer (score -2):

'System.InvalidCastException' -> says you that you have made wrong cast.

So if we will take special range of items from list,
after **cast** them to (**int**),
then we get result of **unboxing**.

Because **boxing** has been made when you added numbers to Lis.

Hope this detailed response will be more friendfull.

List listOfObjects = new List();
            //var listOfObjects = new List();

```
        //adding first string to list
        listOfObjects.Add("First string");

        //adding integers to list
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            listOfObjects.Add(j);
        }
        listOfObjects.Add("Second string");
        for (int k = 5; k < 10; k++)
        {
            listOfObjects.Add(k);
        }
        foreach (var obj in listOfObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
        }
        var sum = 0;
        for (var l = 0; l < 4; l++)
        {

            var a = listOfObjects[l].GetType();

            if (a == typeof(int))
            {
                sum += (int)listOfObjects[l];
                Console.WriteLine("I've get an integer type.");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("I've get only string type.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);

        Console.Read();
```

Hope this modified sample will help you. Good Luck!